# Javascript Validate Input fields + Select Field

Tags: javascript

I am using a very easy (but functional for my needs) Javascript script to validate input fields.

Here my main code:

```
<script language = "javascript">
function manage(txt) {
    var bt = document.getElementById('send');
    if (txt.value && txt2.value && txt3.value != '') {
        bt.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        bt.disabled = true;
    }
}       
</script>
```

Here are my fields

```
    <input type="text" name="FNAME" id="txt" class="input" size="20" placeholder="First Name *" onkeyup="manage(this)">
    <input type="text" name="LNAME" id="txt2" class="input" size="20" placeholder="Last Name *" onkeyup="manage(this)">
    <input type="text" name="EMAIL" id="txt3" class="input" size="20" placeholder="Email *" onkeyup="manage(this)">
```

and here my Submit button:

```
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="send" class="button button-primary" value="Subscribe" disabled>
```

What this does is to leave the submit button disabled until all fields have some value entered and works absolutely fine, however I also have a new and additional select option being:

```
    <select name="Countries">
            <option value="">Select Country</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            ......
    </select>
```

I've tried to apply the following changes:

```
<script language = "javascript">
function manage(txt) {
    var bt = document.getElementById('send');
    if (txt.value && txt2.value && txt3.value && txt4.value != '') {
        bt.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        bt.disabled = true;
    }
}       
</script>

    <select name="Countries" id="txt4" onkeyup="manage(this)">
            <option value="">Select Country</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
            ......
    </select>
```

However it does not seem to work. Some expert advise would be greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Just for the future usage: try to avoid `!=` and use `!==` instead, it will prevent you from some JS weird parts. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper form is

```
if (txt.value!='' && txt2.value!='' && txt3.value!='' && txt4.value!='')
```

You don't want to set the `onkyeup` event, but `onchange`. More universal event is [oninput](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/oninput).

You should also check the `required` form elements tag attribute, which can provide you similar functionality without javascript. [See here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation).

Comment: That worked, thank you very much, especially the onchange part.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, listening `keyup` event on your select will work only in case if select was changed by the keyboard. In case if it was changed by mouse, your event won't be fired. Better to listen `onchange`

On another hand, you should check the emptiness of all text fields, as you do for `txt4.value!=''`:

```
if (txt.value!='' && txt2.value!='' && txt3.value!='' && txt4.value!='') {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Now it will work.

```js
function manage(txt) {
    var bt = document.getElementById('send');
    if ( txt.value != '' && txt2.value != '' && txt3.value != '' && txt4.value != '' ) {
        bt.disabled = false;
    }
    else {
        bt.disabled = true;
    }
}
```

```html
 <input type="text" name="FNAME" id="txt" class="input" size="20" placeholder="First Name *" onkeyup="manage(this)">
    <input type="text" name="LNAME" id="txt2" class="input" size="20" placeholder="Last Name *" onkeyup="manage(this)">
    <input type="text" name="EMAIL" id="txt3" class="input" size="20" placeholder="Email *" onkeyup="manage(this)">
 <select name="Countries" id="txt4" onchange="manage(this)">
                <option value="">Select Country</option>
                <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
                <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
              
        </select>

      <input type="submit" name="submit" id="send" class="button button-primary" value="Subscribe" disabled>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have done this type of functionality before. So I'm sharing my code here. 
**HTML Code**

```
<form method="Post" class="form">
    <input type="text" name="FNAME" id="txt" class="input" size="20" placeholder="First Name *" onblur="manage(this)">
    <input type="text" name="LNAME" id="txt2" class="input" size="20" placeholder="Last Name *" onblur="manage(this)">
    <input type="text" name="EMAIL" id="txt3" class="input" size="20" placeholder="Email *" onblur="manage(this)">
    <select name="Countries" id="txt4"  onchange="manage(this)" class="input">
            <option value="">Select Country</option>
            <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
            <option value="Åland Islands">Åland Islands</option>
            <option value="Albania">Albania</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" id="send" class="button button-primary" value="Subscribe" disabled>
</form>
```

**Javascript Code:**

```
<script>
function manage($e){
    var input = document.getElementsByClassName("input");  
    var status=false;
    for(var i=0;i<input.length;i++){
        if(input[i].value.trim()!='' && input[i].value.trim()!=null && input[i].value.trim()!=undefined){
            status = true;
        } else {
            status = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    console.log(status);
    if(status===true){
        var email = document.getElementById("txt3").value;  
        if(!(/^([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-])+\@(([a-zA-Z0-9-])+\.)+([a-zA-Z0-9]{2,4})+$/.test(email.trim()))){console.log('1');
            document.getElementById('send').disabled = true;
        } else {console.log('2');
            document.getElementById('send').disabled = false;
        }       
    } else {
        document.getElementById('send').disabled = true;
    }
}

</script>
```

There are many ways to resolve this type of functionality but for this case, I have used the above code to achieve the goal. If you have any queries, please let me know. Thanks.